# Creating a graph network using d3 v5: error generating the links/edges between nodes

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm currently trying to replicate the following graph network (https://bl.ocks.org/mapio/53fed7d84cd1812d6a6639ed7aa83868) with my own data. The issue that I have has to do with generating the links/edges between nodes.

The error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: `missing: B_01_062`

Is occurring from this line:

```
.force("link", d3.forceLink(graph.links).id(function (d) { return d.id; }).distance(50).strength(1))
```

Which is where the graph layout variable is defined. If you comment out this line, the graph will generate with just the nodes.

I've tried converting the graph object returned from the d3.tojson function into an in place javascript object structured like this.

```
var g = {
    nodesL: [...], 
    linksL: [...]
}
```

This did not work either.

Here is a subset of the example data looks like:

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "id": "Myriel",
      "group": 1
    },
    {
      "id": "Napoleon",
      "group": 1
    },
    {
      "id": "Mlle.Baptistine",
      "group": 1
    },
   ]
  "links": [
      {
      "source": "Napoleon",
      "target": "Myriel",
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "source": "Mlle.Baptistine",
      "target": "Myriel",
      "value": 8
    },
    {
      "source": "Mme.Magloire",
      "target": "Myriel",
      "value": 10
    },
   ]
}
```

Here is a subset of my current data looks like:

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "id": "&=ARMS-CROSS", "Code": "J_01_098", "NeighborhoodDensity": 3}, 
    {
      "id": "&=CLAP", "Code": "J_02_076", "NeighborhoodDensity": 3}, 
    {
      "id": "&=RAISE-HAND", "Code": "H_02_48", "NeighborhoodDensity": 3},

  "links": [
      {
        source: "B_01_062", 
        target: "A_01_002"
      },
      {
        source: "B_03_025", 
        target: "A_01_002"
      },
      {
        source: "C_03_023", 
        target: "A_01_002"
      }
   ]
}
```

I've even tried converting the source and target values to actual numbers.

```
// convert to a javascript object
    function convertToObj(link_obj) {
        var conv_obj = {}

        // conv_obj.source = link_obj['source'];
        // conv_obj.target = link_obj['target'];

        conv_obj.source = parseInt(link_obj['source'].replace(/\D[^\.]/g, ""));
        conv_obj.target = parseInt(link_obj['target'].replace(/\D[^\.]/g, ""));

        // console.log(conv_obj.source);
        // console.log(conv_obj.target);
        // console.log(conv_obj);

        return conv_obj;
    }
```

The links array will look like this

```
    links: [
        {
         source: 162, 
         target: 102
        },
        {
         source: 325, 
         target: 102
        },
        {
         source: 323, 
         target: 102
        }
    ]
```

Comment: What does your link data look like?

Comment: The link data is an array of link (javascript objects).

Comment: all the data is stored in a json object, just like the example, I've displayed the subset of each data above, sorry if i was not clear.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the links array?

Comment: sorry about that, I just did.